# Druid aggregate functions

Tags: druid

I am using druid to create a UI for generating reports. For the scripting, I am using the following codes:

```
        {
      "type" : "doubleSum",
      "name" : "impressions",
      "fieldName" : "impressions"
    },
    {
      "type" : "doubleSum",
      "name" : "clicks",
      "fieldName" : "clicks"
    },
    {
      "type" : "doubleSum",
      "name" : "pvconversions",
      "fieldName" : "pvconversions"
    },
    {
      "type" : "doubleSum",
      "name" : "pcconversions",
      "fieldName" : "pcconversions"
    }
```

I need two more fields:

```
Total Conversions = pvconversions+pcconversions
CTR = Clicks / Impressions
```

I havent been able to find anything regarding this matter about how to write them.
Can anyone help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue can be resolve using aggregations and postAggregations like this snippets below:

```
{
  "queryType":"timeseries",
  "dataSource":"data",
  "granularity":"hour",
  "descending":"false",
  "aggregations":[
    {"type":"doubleSum", "name":"sum-pvconversions", "fieldName":"pvconversions"},
    {"type":"doubleSum", "name":"sum-pcconversions", "fieldName":"pcconversions"},
    {"type":"doubleSum", "name":"sum-clicks", "fieldName":"clicks"},
    {"type":"doubleSum", "name":"sum-impressions", "fieldName":"impressions"}
    ],
  "postAggregations":[
    {
      "type":"arithmetic",
      "name":"Conversions",
      "fn":"+",
      "fields":[
        {"type":"fieldAccess", "name":"postAgg-proceed", "fieldName":"sum-pvconversions"},
        {"type":"fieldAccess", "name":"postAgg-numbers", "fieldName":"sum-pcconversions"}
        ]
    },
    {
      "type":"arithmetic",
      "name":"CTR",
      "fn":"/",
      "fields":[
        {"type":"fieldAccess", "name":"postAgg-click", "fieldName":"sum-clicks"},
        {"type":"fieldAccess", "name":"postAgg-impression", "fieldName":"sum-impressions"}
        ]
    }
    ],
  "intervals":["2016-08-22T01/2016-08-29T03"],
  "context":{
    "skipEmptyBuckets":"true"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using aggregate in timeseries query. Is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: Here is the link if you are looking which will be helpful - http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/aggregations.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use post aggregates in the query.
From the documentation of Druid

> Post-aggregations are specifications of processing that should happen on aggregated values as they come out of Druid. If you include a post aggregation as part of a query, make sure to include all aggregators the post-aggregator requires

For example to calculate CTR, here is the post aggregate:

```
"postAggregations" : [{
     "type"   : "arithmetic",
     "name"   : "average",
     "fn"     : "*",
    "fields" : [
       { "type"   : "arithmetic",
         "name"   : "CTR",
         "fn"     : "/",
         "fields" : [
           { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "clicks", "fieldName" : "clicks" },
           { "type" : "fieldAccess", "name" : "impressions", "fieldName" : "impressions" }
         ]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregations in Druid can only be used with aggregation queries like timeseries, topN and groupBy.

If you're just aggregating values in a column against time, the simplest way to do it would be to write a timeseries query.

For example,

```
{
  "queryType": "timeseries",
  "dataSource": "<datasource name>",
  "granularity": "day",
  "aggregations": [
    <Your aggregations here>
  ],
  "intervals": [ <Time interval (from/to)> ]
}
```